# Search return wrong result with special character like æ ø å in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, search

I had created search in Craft 3, but it returns wrong result when I enter some special characters in it, for example æ ø å. Looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible natively.  Craft runs each search keyword through a "normalization" process before saving in its search index and part of that is converting characters like `å` to their ASCII counterparts `a`.  You can see the whole process here:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/Search.php#L41

If this were solely in the context of the searching on the front-end of the site, you could use/write a plugin that integrated with a 3rd party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) that offered more flexible options, but that wouldn't affect Control Panel searching until this was implemented: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/833